# Date Highlight Formula Excel conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I making a leave Planner which highlight the calendar as per the dates 
using these formulas

```
=IF(B6="",FALSE,SUMPRODUCT((B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[Start]"))*(B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[End]"))))

=IF(B6="",FALSE,SUMPRODUCT((B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[SD1]"))*(B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[ED1]"))))
```

I want to apply this formula on same row not on columns how i can give range of Rows or range of cells containing start dates and end dates so same color highlight for one row and other color for other row

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formulas would be:

```
=OR(SUMPRODUCT((B6<>"")*("abc"=INDIRECT("Table1[Names]"))*(B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[Start]"))*(B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[End]"))),SUMPRODUCT((B6<>"")*("abc"=INDIRECT("Table1[Names]"))*(B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[SD1]"))*(B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[ED1]"))),SUMPRODUCT((B6<>"")*("abc"=INDIRECT("Table1[Names]"))*(B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[SD1]"))*(B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[ED1]"))))
```

As you can see you will need to have a different rule for each name.  And change the name.

Comment: yes it is working but problem is if ABC and DEF are applying for same date it is highlighting only the first one is it possible to have the Red color if dates are same in  COLUMN e,g if start date and end end date for ABC and DEF is same it should Highlight color RED

Comment: @KzhelFarmer Yes you can put both formulas together with `AND(Formula1,Formula2)`  Make sure it is the first rule in `manage rules` so it has highest priority.

Comment: can you give me formula cuz i have 15 Rows and 20 Columns my formula getting very big and suggest Plz formula for If Same dates in Columns