# Different color of same date range in a column Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have leave manager i want to color different if two or more dates are same
i am using this formula

```
=OR(SUMPRODUCT((B6<>"")* (B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[Start]"))*(B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[End]"))) ,SUMPRODUCT((B6<>"")* (B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[S1]"))*(B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[E1]"))) ,SUMPRODUCT((B6<>"")* (B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[S2]"))*(B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[E2]"))) ,SUMPRODUCT((B6<>"")* (B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[S3]"))*(B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[E3]"))) ,SUMPRODUCT((B6<>"")* (B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[S4]"))*(B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[E4]"))) ,SUMPRODUCT((B6<>"")* (B6>=INDIRECT("Table1[S5]"))*(B6<=INDIRECT("Table1[E5]"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: @Druzion nothing wrong with code it is working but if same dates are in columns it is highlight only once i want if same dates occur it should color Red

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Comment: I just answered your question back on your original, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374854/date-highlight-formula-excel-conditional-formatting/34376967#34376967).

Comment: You are making it harder than it needs to be.  The formula will work with the table in columnar form.  You can have multiple lines in your table for each employee and it will work fine with the formula with just the name, Start and End.  It will find each line that the name is "def" or "abc".  You do not need to make one line so long.  It will work better and the formula will be shorter.

Comment: @Scott Craner can you give me formula cuz i have 15 Rows and 20 Columns my formula getting very big and suggest Plz formula for If Same dates in Columns and file is taking time to open and close

Comment: I am going to be busy with family for the next 4 hours.    Also as I thought about it, you do not need 20 columns only 3.  Each employee would use a new line in the table for each leave.  The formula could be shortened to one sumproduct without the `OR`.  Then you would use `SUM(SumProduct Formula without the name part)>1` to indicate having more than one time scheduled.  I will mock something up when I get done with family obligations.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks actually separate row for each staff and each staff different color and each staff can apply max 8 times leave in a year that is why start date and end dates are in columns also if two staff apply same time it should highlight red instead of one staff allocated color

Comment: It would still be one separate color per employee.  As to the max number a forth column could be added that has a counter to indicate which leave is being requested. But to each his own, Again I will work more on it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you want with all the columns is:

```
=1 < SUM(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Table1[Start]"),"<=" & B6,INDIRECT("Table1[End]"),">="& B6),COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Table1[SD1]"),"<=" & B6,INDIRECT("Table1[ED1]"),">="& B6),...),0)
```

Where the `...` is more countifs for the number of groupings

---

But that is not using Excel's functions to their potential.  As I said in my comments, fewer columns allows for the same functionality with shorter and more accurate formulas.

[image]

The formula in the count column is:

```
=IF(Z5<>"",COUNTIF($Z$5:$Z5,Z5),"")
```

You could put a conditional formatting on this column to highlight when they have reached the 8 max:

```
=AC5 >= 8
```

Then the conditional formatting in the calendars would be:

[image]

For the overlap:

```
= 1 < COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Table3[Start]"),"<=" & B6,INDIRECT("Table3[End]"),">=" & B6)
```

For the employee:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("Table3[Names]")="abc")*(INDIRECT("Table3[Start]")<=B6)*(INDIRECT("Table3[End]")>=B6))
```

Again Changing the name of the employee.

With the data formatted as a table the reference will grow to accommodate new entries.  Since the formula requires the employee name it does not matter if there is 1 or 100 entries for that employee it will always be the same color.

Also this allow one to use the filters that are inherent in the table, to sort and filter on employees and dates.