# Cell value in calendar instead of Highlight

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am having a leave calendar which is highlighting the dates as per employee leave date in calendar using a conditional formatting which is working perfect but i want instead of highlight it display Name mentioned in front of date into the calendar.

> =SUMPRODUCT((B3<=$I$19:$I$150)*(B3>=$E$19:$E$150))=1

[image: cal]

I want to show name in calendar instead of green highlight.
Formula or VBA; anything is acceptable.

Comment: An answer is going to depend on how you input the month names in A3:A14. At first I thought they were just text typed due to the cell left-alignment but then I noticed you forced left alignment on the dates in the merged cells E19:L22. So A3:A14 could be actual dates formatted as `mmmm` with forced left alignment. What are they?

Comment: @Jeeped Calendar is with formula "=DATE($D$1,ROWS($A$3:$A3),B$2)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In B3 put this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$20:$A$151,MATCH(1,IF(DATE($D$1,ROWS($A$3:$A3),B$2)>=$E$20:$E$151,IF(DATE($D$1,ROWS($A$3:$A3),B$2)<=$I$20:$I$151,1)),0)),"")
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then Copy Down and Across.

[image]

If the name is only necessary in the first day of the holiday period then a simpler [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair will suffice.

In B3 as,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$20:$A$150,  MATCH(DATE(YEAR($A3), MONTH($A3), B$2), $E$20:$E$150, 0)), "")
```

Fill right and down.

[image: holiday_planner_calendar2]

Notes:

These will only return the first name if there are overlaps.

Depending on your local seetings you may need to change the delimiter from `,` to `;`.

If you still want you conditional formatting then change the conditional formatting formula to:

```
=B3<>""
```

Comment: Nice formula but I think the name was only intended to go into the first cell of the holiday span (*'mentioned in front of date into the calendar'*). Should actually be a bit easier.

Comment: @Jeeped That is definitely a possibility that I missed.  As I literally just walked out my door, I will be unable to change it.  If you want, feel free to edit mine and make it a community wiki, or post your own addressing that understanding.  I will leave it here just in case.

Comment: @Scott Craner that is what i intend to do but is it possible in case of two or three on same date to show like (ABC/DEF/HGK)

Comment: @KzhelFarmer In which case, use a separate lookup table that first combines the names by first date.. or use VBA.

Comment: @KzhelFarmer As ti7 said, if that is the desire than vba is the best, Formulas do not work well with unknowns, like the number of people names to concatenate.  The only way with formulas is to concatenate one formula for every employee,  So you would take a modified version of my formula using the `SMALL()` function which would make it longer and multiply it by the number of employees.  The formula would be huge and would be prone to error.  Also that is a new question and I answered your original and it should be mark as correct.  If you want to ask a new question write a new post.

Comment: @Scott Craner First one is working good that is what i need but what is for duplicates eg (ASH/ABD/XYZ) in case same dates to show 2 or 3 people on same day

Comment: @KzhelFarmer That is a new question, please ask in a new post.  Another option;  See [THIS POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382107/different-color-of-same-date-range-in-a-column-excel/34385619#34385619) it is a different method to do what you are asking, each person gets a color and when they overlap it turns red.

Comment: @KzhelFarmer never mind the link just realized it was yours.

Comment: @Scott Craner thanks for that one i have to use this name option cuz highlight is not clear that who 2 or 3 people on leave this name will show in a glance

Comment: @ScottCraner if you know VBA option can you please suggest

Comment: @KzhelFarmer NEW QUESTION = NEW POST.  before you do if you want an answer in vba, you will need to try on your own then come back with specific question as to why it is not doing what it should.  I answered your original question.

Comment: @KzhelFarmer - How did I know you were going to chenge the conditions of the question as soon as you received an answer? Just experience with these types of questions I guess. The answer is **NO YOU CANNOT DO THAT!**. Your column widths are too narrow to allow more than a single three character 'name'. The text **CANNOT** spill into the next cell because that cell will have a formula as well; even if that second cell returns `""`, that is sufficient to truncate the text spilling over from the first cell.

Comment: @KzhelFarmer - You would need to completely **ABANDON** any formula based solution in favor of a VBA procedure; possibly [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro triggered on additions to the Start Date column.

Comment: @KzhelFarmer - Changing the conditions of the question sufficiently that very valid proposed solutions are no longer valid is considered very bad etiquette indeed. If you have finally figured out what you need, then close this question off either by marking one of the proposed solutions as the 'accepted answer' or delete the question altogether. Start a new question with your revised requirements. btw, people asking for VBA code are **expected** to show original effort. [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is **NOT** a 'gimme teh codez' site.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for reply but before i get your reply i did accept the answer and preparing a new one based on mixture of VBA and formula